# DOM undefined when the element is inside a *ngIf container

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

my problem is that i cant acces to a particular DOM element and their properties when the element is a children of a *ngIf container.

My case is: I a have a mat-table inside a div, the div have the *ngIf directive, and then i try to call mytable.renderRows() when my datasource changed, but i got an undefined value. I see this problem happens when the element is inside the ngIf directive, in other case i can access without problem.

```
<div *ngIf="!hasPermission" >
    <table mat-table #myTable [dataSource]="myDataSource">
```

and i have this on the .ts file:

```
export class MyComponent {

   hasPermission = true

   @ViewChild('myTable',{static:true}) myTable: MatTable<any>;

   constructor(){
      if(checkSomething == true){
          this.hasPermission = false
          this.myFunctionIfNotHavePermsissions()
      }
   }

   myFunctionIfNotHavePermsissions(){
      this.myTable.renderRows();
      // console.log(this.myTable); *NOTE: This output: undefined*
   }

}
```

For the moment, I fixed this problem, hidding the div using css, but i think this not the best solution, thanks in advance for your comments.

```
<div *ngIf="!hasPermission" >

to

<div [ngClass]="{ 'nodisplay': !hasPermission}" >

.nodisplay{display:none!important;}
```

Comment: As @miladfm answered, `static: true` decorator of your `@ViewChild` makes your element acessible on component scope only at `ngOnInit` execution forward, so, instead of adding your logic on your constructor, try to replace it inside of the init lifecycle hook component.

Answer (score 1):

I may don't know the actual reason behind it, but I think angular need a little time to first render whatever inside the **ngIf** element and then make available to DOM.

You can fix your issue by changing **static** to **false** here

```
@ViewChild('myTable', {static: false}) myTable: MatTable<any>;
```

and calling **this.myFunctionIfNotHavePermsissions()** inside a **setTimeout**

```
constructor(){
  if(checkSomething == true){
      this.hasPermission = false
      setTimeout(()=> this.myFunctionIfNotHavePermsissions());
  }
}
```

Comment: i only change the static to false, and works!!

Answer (score 1):

in constructor you the template is not ready and mat-table is not rendered.

add your logic in `ngOnInit`

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

   hasPermission = true

   @ViewChild('myTable',{static:true}) myTable: MatTable<any>;


   constructor() {}


   ngOnInit() {
      if(checkSomething == true){
          this.hasPermission = false
          this.myFunctionIfNotHavePermsissions()
      }
   }

   myFunctionIfNotHavePermsissions(){
      this.myTable.renderRows();
      // console.log(this.myTable); *NOTE: This output: undefined*
   }

}
```

Comment: i move the logic to ngOnInit and the problem continue, but if I change the static to false, it seems not it necesary move the logic to ngOnInit